# jq breaks reading encoded entities from valid JSON string

Tags: bash, sed, jq

I'm using `jq` to iterate through a JSON file and am having issues with occurrences of `\u0022` within the json values.

```
jq -c  '.node[]' file.json | while read node; do

    description=$(jq -r '.description' <<< "$node");

    printf '%s\n' "$description";


done
```

This works for all values except that `jq` decodes the values which causes an error when encountering `\u0022` since it translates to a double quote.

So for a value of

```
{"description":"This is my \u0022real\u0022 name"}
```

`jq` will error with: `parse error: Invalid numeric literal`

How do I get `jq` to NOT decode the entities or ignore or remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all; rather than iterating the JSON `node` array using Bash, you could as well offload it entirely to `jq` with:

```sh
jq -r '.node[]|.description' file.json
```

About your issue with parsing the `$node` Bash variable with `jq` when it contains double quotes `"`; is because the `read` command needs a `-r` option or it will un-escape the double-quotes (remove the backslash `\`) from the JSON string, turning it into an invalid JSON string.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jq -c  '.node[]' file.json | while read -r node; do
echo "$node"
    description=$(jq -r '.description' <<< "$node");
    printf '%s\n' "$description";
done
```

Also this Bash script will fail if the `.node[]` array is empty or non-existent, because `jq` is going to parse an empty input.